# Interpretation of Interesting Utility Function

Tags: microeconomics, utility, cobb-douglas

Solving introductory microeconomics problems I have come across the following type of utility function:
$$ f(K,L) = (\alpha K^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} + (1 - \alpha) L^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}})^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma - 1}} $$

I find it slightly reminiscent of the logarithm version of the Cobb-Douglas function, but clearly the exponents don't fit with that. So the question is: **How would you interpret $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ in this case?**. Is $\alpha$ still the relative fraction of capital and labour? How can I think about $\sigma$?

Comment: This does not seem to be a utility function, but a production function.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is $\alpha$ still the relative fraction of capital and labour"? Even in the Cobb-Douglas function $\alpha \ln K + (1 - \alpha) \ln L$ the parameter does not show the ratio $K/L$.

Comment: @denesp the question I have come across explicitly states that this is a utility function and that $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ should be interpreted from that point of view. 
However, apologies for the faulty description of "relative fraction". What I meant was $L/F$ and $K/F$.

Comment: @denesp So is Cobb-Douglas -but it is used also to model utility.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos My comment was on the notations $f$, $K$ and $L$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [CES production function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_elasticity_of_substitution), where CES stands for constant elasticity of substitution.

The parameter $\sigma$ captures the (constant) elasticity of substitution and $\alpha$ is the share parameter.

The Cobb-Douglas production function can be obtained as a special case of the CES class by taking $\sigma\to1$. For proof, I'd refer you to [this post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/361/42).