# How can I prove $U(x) = [_1_1^+_2_2^]^{(1/)}$ is equal to Cobb-douglas Utility function when $\rightarrow0$

Tags: microeconomics, utility

This is the question, I have problem with part b, I don't know what function should I use to reach the result
thanks in forward
[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where users must demonstrate effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site. Using only images as proof of work is insufficient. for more details see:https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I obtain Leontief and Cobb-Douglas production function from CES function?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/361/how-can-i-obtain-leontief-and-cobb-douglas-production-function-from-ces-function)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: find $\ln(U(x))$ and then use L'Hopital's rule to find the limit as $\rho\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint:** you are supposed to show the utility function represents the same preferences not that the utility functions are exactly same. Recall that any monotonic transformations of function preserves the original order of preferences. So you only need to show that in the limit one function is monotonic transformation of the other.

Comment: well actually I tried to use ln to show it but I couldn't find the relation that's what I asked it here, I guess I asked the wrong question