# Can someone help me prove that the CES function is also a Cobb-Douglass function

Tags: mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, cobb-douglas, price-theory

I would like some assistance with a problem that I have showing a CES function is also a Cobb-Douglass utility function.

Question: we have a CES function: $Y=A[\alpha K^{((1-\sigma)/\sigma))}+(1-\alpha) L^{(\sigma-1)/(\sigma)}]^{\sigma/(\sigma-1)}$ $\sigma \geq 0$ $\alpha\in [0,1]$ show it is equivalent to Cobb- Douglass when sigma equals 1

Attempted solution:

$Y=$ $A[\alpha K^{((1-\sigma)/\sigma))}+(1-\alpha) L^{(\sigma-1)/(\sigma)}]^{\sigma/(\sigma-1)}$

$\ln Y=$ $ \ln[A[\alpha K^{((1-\sigma)/\sigma))}+(1-\alpha) L^{(\sigma-1)/(\sigma)}]^{\sigma/(\sigma-1)}]$

$\ln Y=$ $ \frac{\sigma \ln [A[\alpha K^{((1-\sigma)/\sigma))}+(1-\alpha) L^{(\sigma-1)/(\sigma)}]}{\sigma-1}$

Then I take the limit of both sides as $\sigma$ approaches 1

$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 1} \ln Y= \\ 
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 1}\frac{\sigma \ln [A[\alpha K^{((1-\sigma)/\sigma))}+(1-\alpha) L^{(\sigma-1)/(\sigma)}]}{\sigma-1}$

I am stuck here. I keep getting $\frac{\ln[1]}{0}=\frac{0}{0}$.

My guess is tht I should use L’hops rule, but I am not sure if my function is differentiable. Even then I doubt I could solve such a complex derivative. Any thoughts, advice, etc.? Also, if I can take the derivative how do I do so? (It’s been a while, LOL)

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same problem already solved [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/361/how-can-i-obtain-leontief-and-cobb-douglas-production-function-from-ces-function?rq=1) just with different notation. Can you please explain why that answer did not solved your problem? Otherwise this would be a duplicate.

Comment: My apologies. I did not see that problem. Unfortunately it still did not answer my question in full. I was unsure if my calculus was correct up to that point.

Comment: then please explain in your answer why. As far as I can see the two functions are identical once you substitute $\sigma=1/(1+\rho)$ and set k=1. If you think your problem is different or that solution there does not apply here please edit your question and explain why this should be different problem

Comment: That would be why I assumed my calculus was different. I made an error with $\sigma$. Thank you for catching that.